# View is dependent on Model (MVC)

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I built a Event Notification system that receives events generated by devices. I had 2 main components: Listener and Publisher. Publisher will send polling command to device and catches the events. Then, it will notify all events to Listener via EventBus (I used EventBus library of Guava). Now I implement a View component. View is Observer and Model is Observable. When listener receives an event, it will notify to Views. 
View extends JFrame and implements Observer. In the constructor like:
public View(Listener), I just register View as an Observer to Listener

The problem is when I close the view, the program is closed too. How can I make the view independent on Model?
Please help me.

Comment: A quick fix is to set the JFrame's defaultCloseOperation to JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE. A better solution is to perhaps separate your view from your model even more, perhaps running them on different JVM's, giving them some mechanism for communication, perhaps via Streams as a simple way to do this. There are higher level ways of doing this that allow transfer of objects (I think RMI and JINI are examples), but I've never done this and so cannot speak from experience -- which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Maybe you could share some of your code so one could see what exactly is closing your program. Otherwise it would be wild guessing for example you could be using System.exit(0) in some form to close your view instead of da dispose like hovercraft sugested..

Comment: @Akunosh: `System.exit(...)` is the last thing he wants to do if the view and model are run on the same JVM. It will guarantee that the model will shut down and is exactly the opposite of what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: hi @HovercraftFullOfEels, I thought about your solution. Because the view is created in the same main() class with model. But I dont know how to implement that mechanism.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know. Maybe i translated it the wrong way. I just suspect the code currently to contain some form of System.exit(...), like e.g. JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE. What I wanted to say is that noone can know what actually closes his model from his description alone.

Comment: @Akunosh, Your suggestion worked well. I closed View but the program does not close. But That 's not complete my expectation. I want something like Listener is singleton, So I can create View1 listens to Listener, then closing View1, then creating a View2 listens to Listener,....

Comment: @xuongrong: your requirements are shifting which makes it difficult if not impossible to answer your question since it's like trying to hit a moving target. Please ask a complete question from the start so that we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Sorry because I'm not writing clear. Honestly, Before posting this question, I searched singleton model for MVC

Comment: @xuongrong: singleton is not the answer and is often considered an "anti-pattern", a bad coding practice.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will post another question, Thanks you and Mr.Akunosh help me.

Comment: cause they are different layers , may be they have to live in different world, but this take more time of developing, and you have to use some communication from view to model

Comment: @nachokk: Do you have any sample code or link about that? thanks

Comment: first of all, you should separate your projects, what is gui and what it isn't, could be 3 projects, 1- view (frames etc) 2- controller and application logic() , 3- model domain()

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a control package, which would be responsible for sending messages from the view to the model.